# vertical align with specific margin top and bottom

Tags: javascript, alignment, margin, css-position, vertical-alignment

I have a div (the green one) positioned in the middle of the window but I want that when I resize the window, this div ALWAYS respect a margin (the height of the logo and the footer).

I really don't get it. Could anyone have a look at it? The proyect is this one: http://sfrpsicologia.com/inicio.html

Thanks for everything

Comment: i can't  see any green div??? or do you mean the menu???

Comment: Sorry, it is once you have entered in one of the options of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

give ol & li width using %

Comment: this doesnt solve my problem. could you be more specific please?